# google nest hub can't play hls

Tags: http-live-streaming, google-smart-home

*My Question is*

I push HLS steram to **gnh**(google nest hub) by `action.devices.commands.GetCameraStream` response format.**gnh** do nothing but show loading UI some seconds.

It's somthing wrong with my HLS file?

How to get log from **gnh** to help me debug?

*As I know*

I am tried to push mp4(1080p/under 60 fps) url to **gnh**, that's work well.

I am tried to convert mp4 to hls by some lib,include ffmpeg,Bento4.

*Here is my JSON send to **gnh**:*

```
{
    "payload":  {
        "commands": [{
                "status":   "SUCCESS",
                "states":   {
                    "cameraStreamAccessUrl":    "http:/path/of/steram.m3u8"
                },
                "ids":  ["....."]
            }]
    },
    "requestId":    "My_Request_Id"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing the required property cameraStreamSupportedProtocols. Try adding the protocol and see if you are able to get the stream to work. This will load the default cast camera receiver since you are trying to play HLS content. If you are still seeing an issue with playback, it could be that your stream is malformed and needs to be revised.

Playback logs will only be available to you if you create your own basic receiver app and specify this in your response using the cameraStreamReceiverAppId property. To see more about creating a cast receiver app refer to the overview page (https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/web_receiver) and how to create a basic receiver (https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/web_receiver/basic) for more information. We also do have a default camera receiver sample located in our sample github (https://github.com/googlecast/CastCameraReceiver)